# ASP.NET MVC Core - replace controllers using custom class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have core product with some MVC controller.

I want to have ability to overwrite some actions specific to the client using custom class library (Let's say MyProduct.MVC.Custom.dll).

In previous versions of MVC it was possible using routes.MapRoute( namespaces: new[] { "MyProduct.MVC.Custom" }

In current MVC we do not have such option and I receiving the following error message:

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> MyProduct.MVC.Custom.Controllers.HomeController.About
>
> MyProduct.MVC.Controllers.HomeController.About
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionSelector.SelectAsync(RouteContext context)

Google suggest me to use Areas, but I want to replace the controller's action with the same URL.

Is it possible to achieve this is ASP.NET MVC core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally manage how to do it.

It can be achieved using the `Route` attribute with `Order=0`

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]",Name ="Replacement", Order = 0)]
public IActionResult About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "This is About from Custom controller!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";

    return View();
}
```